# CloudPagesURL is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have created a Unsubscribe page on which i am passing Email address and Sub Key from Email. I have personalized the url's as below when i click on this link it's not opening the page. If I hard coded the link it's working fine. Is there anything that I am missing here?

```
<span style="font-size:11px;">If you no longer wish to receive these emails you may 

   <p>
       <a title="MyPage" href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123))=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">Click to unsubscribe</a>
   </p>

   <span style="font-size:11px;">If you no longer wish to receive these emails you may <a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123,'EmailAddress',emailaddr, 'Subscriberkey', _subscriberkey))=%%" alias="Unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</a> at any time.</span>
   <br>
 <br>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm whether you're not redirecting to the cloud page or you're seeing error on the cloud page when clicked on the link?

Comment: I am using test send to test the email. Once i used Data extension to select the subscriber link started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the sample code in your post, [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) AMPScript function should pass the **_subscriberkey** and **emailaddr** to the respected cloudpage ID by default.

- As you mentioned in the comment that you're using **Test Send** feature and this won't execute the AMPScripts thus the CloudPagesURL function didn't get executed. The best practice is to perform a guided send or a send preview option against a subscriber Data Extension or a list.
- To test personalization strings, AMPScript and/or dynamic content on a subscriber-by-subscriber basis, see Send Preview.

Note: Test sends won't execute any AMPScript functions within the email body.

[image]